# Convert multiple character columns with numbers and <,> symbols into numeric in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with multiple character columns with numbers and >,< signs.
I want to change them all to numeric.
The values with "<x" are supposed to be halfed and the values with ">x" are supposed to equal to x.

Sample dataframe and my approach (data=labor_df):

```
 data    a      b    c
 1      "1"   "9"  "20" 
 2      "<10" "14" "1.99"
 3      "12"  ">5" "14.5"
   
half.value.a <- (as.numeric(str_extract(labor_df$"a"[which((grepl(labor_df$"a",
                                                                    pattern = c("<"),fixed = T)))], 

"\\d+\\.*\\d*")))/2
min.value.a <- as.numeric(str_extract(labor_df$"a"[which((grepl(labor_df$"a",
                                                                      pattern = c(">"),fixed = T)))], "\\d+\\.*\\d*"))
labor_df$"a"[which((grepl(labor_df$"a",
                             pattern = c("<"),fixed = T)))
] <- half.value.a
labor_df$"a"[which((grepl(labor_df$"a",
                             pattern = c(">"),fixed = T)))
] <- min.value.a
labor_df$"a" <- as.numeric(labor_df$"a")
```

I would like to apply this to multiple columns in my df or use a different approach entirely to convert multiple columns in my df to numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply this approach to whichever columns you want. In this case, if you want to apply to columns 1 through 3, you can specify as `labor_df[1:3]`. If you want to apply to specific columns based on the column name, then create a `cols` vector containing the names of columns to apply this to and use `labor_df[cols]` instead.

The first `gsub` will remove the greater than sign, and keep the value unchanged. The `ifelse` is vectorized and will apply to all values in the column. It will first check with `grepl` if less than sign is present; if it is, remove it, convert to a numeric value, and then divide by 2. Otherwise leave as is.

```
labor_df[1:3] <- lapply(labor_df[1:3], function(x) {
  x <- gsub(">", "", x)
  x <- ifelse(grepl("<", x), as.numeric(gsub("<", "", x)) / 2, x)
  as.numeric(x)
})
labor_df
```

**Output**

```
   a  b     c
1  1  9 20.00
2  5 14  1.99
3 12  5 14.50
```

**Data**

```
labor_df <- structure(list(a = c("1", "<10", "12"), b = c("9", "14", ">5"
), c = c("20", "1.99", "14.5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That completely solved all of my problems!